# I want to create data frame based on some input condition -but seems unable to use dataframe out of if else logic

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I want to create data frame based on some input condition -but seems unable to use dataframe out of if else logic

```
    if(table_1_src =="file") {        
      val df1= spark.read.format("csv")
     .option("path", table_2_path)
     .option("header",true)
     .option("inferSchema",true)
     .load
     }
   df1.show()
    Error: Value not found df1while calling df1.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

you are defining variable inside the scope of `if condition` and that's why it's not available.

This should work.

```scala
val df1 = if(table_1_src =="file") {        
  val df1= spark.read.format("csv")
 .option("path", table_2_path)
 .option("header",true)
 .option("inferSchema",true)
 .load
 df1
 }
df1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the data frame in an inner scope, so it is not visible in the place you want to call it.

You can only reference variables that were declared on at least the same 'level' as the usage place. e.g.

```scala
if(table_1_src =="file") {        
  val df1 = spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("path", table_2_path)
    .option("header",true)
    .option("inferSchema",true)
    .load
  df1.show()
}
```